# Sampling rate conversion for audio using ffmpegwrapper in python

Tags: audio, python

I have many audio files @ 22kHz. I want to convert it to 44.1kHz. Since I have many files to convert, I am looking for an easy solution. I came across ffmpegwrapper for python. I installed the package for python. But I couldnt find out the command to resample. Can anyone please help me ? This is the link for the wrapper. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffmpegwrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) to easily convert your files in one go.

Here are some examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264156/sox-batch-process-under-debian
- https://pwnetics.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/bash-one-liner-using-sox-to-batch-convert-the-sampling-frequency-of-audio-files/

Alternatively, if you want to do this from Python, use [librosa](https://github.com/bmcfee/librosa). An example:

```
By default, librosa will resample the signal to 22050Hz.

You can change this behavior by saying:

librosa.load(audio_path, sr=44100)
to resample at 44.1KHz, or

librosa.load(audio_path, sr=None)
to disable resampling.
```

Answer (score 1):

For complete guide visit this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73891617/14627589)

You can use ffmpeg tool to resample audios. For this, you must have ffmpeg in your environment path variable. You can download ffmpeg for your OS from the given link:

https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

After that extract it and add it to environment variable. Then, use the following Python code to resample:

```
import os

source_file = "path/to/input/file/with/extension"
output_file = "path/to/output/file/with/extension"
cmd_str = f"ffmpeg -i {source_file} -ac 1 -ar 44000 {output_file}"
print(cmd_str)
os.system(cmd_str)
```

I have used this code for my projects and it is working perfect. Replace `44000` with your desired sample rate.